# JavaScript event for when image 'src' attribute is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function `resizePreview()` that will resize an image in a jQuery dialog box if the image is too big.  This image can be changed by the user.  My code goes something like this:

```
$('#imagePreview').attr('src', newImageSrc);
resizePreview();
```

`resizePreview()` uses `$('#imagePreview').width()` and `.height()` to get the dimensions and resizes accordingly. The problem is that the new image isn't loaded by the time `resizePreview()` is called so the image is resized according to it's original dimensions, not according to the dimensions of the newly loaded image.

If I put an `alert()` call in between the two lines of code it works (since the alert gives the browser enough time to load the new image). Apparently I should use an event? Is there an existing event, or is there a way I can make one, for when the image src has changed (sort of like an `onChange` event, but for that attribute) or for when the new image has completed loading?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event works for Images:

```
$('img.userIcon').on('load', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass( 'bigImg', $(this).height() > 100 );
});
```

Comment: I used this code before $(window).load(); and $(document).ready(); and worked.

Answer (score 5):

Image objects allow attachment of onload event listeners:

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function () {
    alert("Loaded");
};
img.src = "dummy-picture.png";
```